# Which other languages have idiomatic meaning for words meaning 'blue'?

Tags: lexical-semantics, idiomaticity

I came across culture-specific meanings of concept 'blue' (that is, of a colour hue between green and violet) in various languages. We know its idiomatic meanings in Standard or American Englishes, but in Russian 'blue' (or, actually, light blue) /голубой/ has an idiomatic meaning 'gay' (referring to sexuality).

In other languages, the word has some other idiomatic meanings, e.g. surprised/drunk in French, or 'police person' (in Latin American Spanish).

Which other languages have specific idiomatic meaning for the colour? Not just in idiomatic sayings (e.g. like 'blue collar', or 'out of the blue'), but rather like a standalone word?

Was such an idiomatic meaning in any ancient languages ever?

Comment: I was under impression that the Russian meaning was borrowed from English, is not it the case?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what will you do with this information? Is it your hypothesis that these idiomatic meanings are related?

Comment: @Anixx I think it is not possible. First, because English does not distiguish between 'light blue' and 'dark blue'. Second, because in Russian the word голубой obtained its meaning from маргаритка, or 'forget-me-not', used in 19th century as a slang word for a homosexual

Comment: See e.g. "Каторга" by Валентин Пикуль: ''В этой громадной толпе, что растекалась сейчас по трапам и люкам, заполняя корабельные трюмы, были представители многих древнейших профессий: маравихеры - карманники, мокрушники - убийцы, блиноделы - фальшивомонетчики, торбохваты - базарные жулики, хомутники - душители, костогрызы - неопытные воришки,... маргаритки - мужчины-проститутки и педерасты, марушники - карманники по церквам и на кладбищах, шопенфиллеры - грабители ювелирных магазинов, халтурщики - ворующие из квартир, где имелся покойник...)

Comment: @acattle: No, I don't think these idiomatic meanins are related, but I know how to use it in my projects.

Comment: @Manjusri forget-me-not is незабудка.

Comment: @bytebuster Right, but the actual word was незабудка, not маргаритка. Пикуль just changed it for phonosemantic reasons.

Comment: @Manjusri I think _Bellis_ has nothing to do about it. For instance, M.Pashkov's article, "Об этимологии слова «голубой» в гомосексуальной коннотации" (in Russian), suggests several compelling versions.

Comment: @bytebuster Yes, I have read it and it was funny, especially postulating 'tenderness, kindness, altruism and peacefulness being qualities the homosexuals value the most' :-))) These qualities have nothing to do with one's sexual preferences. The only reasonable fact in the article was about Перу В. Козловского [1] принадлежит еще одна, не менее оригинальная, версия происхождения слова. Он фиксирует (ссылаясь на Саймона Карлинского) словосочетание «синий цветок» из написанного в 1906 г. письма С. М. Городецкого А. А. Блоку, относящееся к поэту П. П. Потемкину.

Comment: English: blue pictures = porn photos; Irish (and, I vaguely recall, Old Norse): blue person = black person.

Comment: @TRiG Thanks, but these are like 'blue collar'; they don't have a specific meaning unless combined with words 'pictures' or 'person'.

Comment: The Welsh word, _glas_ has connotations of youth, eagerness etc.

Answer (score 1):

In German, being "blau" means being drunk. See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blau.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of *blue* meaning *drunk* or *surprised* in my native [french language](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/french.htm). However, *les bleus* are the cops, for the obvious clothing reason. *Le bleu* is “the new one”, in a job — I have no idea why.

Comment: Are the French national football team not nicknames _Les Bleus_, also?

Comment: Aren't these examples valid then? 6) Vivement surpris de quelque chose.

    J’en étais complètement bleue.

7) (Argot) (Populaire) Complètement ivre.

    Tu aurais vu le Maurice, avec les canons qu’il s’est mis, il était bleu, il divaguait complètement ! http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bleu

Comment: @Danger — 
Yes, the national football team of France is also nicknamed *les Bleus*. I obviously naturally think more about the police than about football. :-)